# Add the hapi 3rd-party lib (jars) to map-reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hapi

I am trying to add the hapi jars to the map-reduce task. I have all the required jars under /home/training/lib
I make the fat jar which contain all the hapi jars that i need and run
`hadoop jar mp.jar stubs.MsgParser infile outfile -libjars /home/training/lib`
i got this 
     `Usage: MsgParser [generic options] <input dir> <output dir>` 
and in my driver i implemented the ToolRunner
**More Info:**

- I am running on CloudEra distribution.
- i need the jars only in the mapper
- mp.jar is exported jar from Eclipse

Is my hadoop jar command need modification or is there any other solution to add these jars, i can't copy the jars to /usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20 cause i am not the owner
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
upload your jars to hdfs and simply add

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path(HDFSPATH), conf);
```

in the main method of the driver